# How to jump to system setting's location service on iOS10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Before I asked this question I had try:

1. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"]];`It's work fine on iOS8 and iOS9,but there is nothing happen on iOS10.
2. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`It's work fine on iOS8 and iOS9,too.However,on iOS10,when the app jump to system setting, the system setting exit immediately.
3. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url options:@{}completionHandler:nil];`It's crashed on iOS8 and iOS9,also,exit immediately on iOS10.

The question is can our app jump to system setting on iOS10? If yes.How?And for `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url options:@{}completionHandler:nil];`what's the `options`means?We must code something for the `options`?

Comment: You can't. You are only permitted to open your own apps settings.

Comment: @Paulw11  How can I open your my apps settings on iOS 10?Please give me a example,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:I use this method for a long time and everyting goes well,but today(2018-9-14),I had been rejected.**

Here is my previous answer,do not use this method forever:

```
CGFloat systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if (systemVersion < 10) {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"]];
}else{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"]
                                          options:[NSDictionary dictionary]
                                completionHandler:nil];
}
```

---

Now I use this way:

```
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:[NSDictionary dictionary] completionHandler:nil];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Your app will be rejected. https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/394

Comment: I have use this method for a long time，everything goes well

Comment: My app got rejected because of this

Comment: @LucasFarah how to do this then

Comment: @ma How to do this then?

Comment: App will be rejected using this method.

Comment: I had got rejected,too.

Comment: @无夜之星辰 had you found any solution, please let me know i am about to update with your solution.

Comment: @ArshadShaik I use my new answer now.Everything goes well.

Comment: @无夜之星辰 if the ios version is >10 or <10 , the code works similar ?. I mean to say, If the ios version is >10, it will go to apps own location service and if <10 it will go to device settings ? Or both lines of code will go to apps own location service ?

Comment: @ArshadShaik They both go to setting.

Answer (score 11):

For some time now, apps have only been permitted to open their own settings pane in the settings app.  There have been various settings URLs that have worked in the past, but recently Apple has been rejecting apps that use these URLS.

You can open your own application's settings:

```
if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Or in Objective-C

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if (url != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:[NSDictionary new] completionHandler:nil];
}
```

If you are targeting version of iOS earlier than 10 then you may prefer to use the older, deprecated, but still functional method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if (url != nil) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Comment: Is that to say,if I open my app own settings pane the Apple would not reject my app,if I use another way to go to settings,Apple would reject？And could you give me a Objective-c code please?I heard some people said that the `options` could not be null.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag.  I have added Objective-C.  You can open your own settings pane without fear of rejection but opening other preferences panes is not permitted.  The options is not nil, it is empty

Comment: @Paulw11, even i got the same issue, i had updated the code as per your suggestion if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) { NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
  if (url != nil) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:[NSDictionary new] completionHandler:nil];} }else{NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]; if (url != nil) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations" [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; #pragma clang diagnostic pop }}

Comment: @Paulw11 i am about to update to appstore for review. Please confirm.

Comment: You should not be rejected for using the code in my answer (or the code you have shown). Make sure you don't have the `prefs:` anywhere in your app, even in a string you don't use as Apple will scan your app when you submit it and detect that string

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i commented the earlier string. and in info URL scheme also i am not adding it.

Comment: if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                if (url != nil) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:[NSDictionary new] completionHandler:nil];
                }
            }

Comment: else{
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                if (url != nil) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
                }
            }

Comment: If you have a rejection from Apple then you probably need to ask them for more details. You should also use the strings command and grep to confirm that the prefs: string doesn't appear in your binaries anywhere.

Comment: @Paulw11, i searched for the prefs: string , it is been commented.

Comment: i got this suggestion from apple, 
Next Steps:To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app requires, you can file an enhancement request.

Comment: `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` resolves to *"app-settings:"*, so it isn't the string the Apple is complaining about.  You should scan your binary as I suggested. Try a clean/build to ensure that the old code isn't in a framework or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181873/discussion-between-arshad-shaik-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 5):

Note :- this solution will not be useful for ios10 onwards

Dont forget to add URL schemes :-

Go to Project settings --> Info --> URL Types --> Add New URL Schemes-->URL Schemes = **prefs**

after that Use this url :-

```
let settingUrl =  URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION")
```

And open using :-

```
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
         UIApplication.shared.open(settingUrl) {
                (isOpen:Bool) in
                if !isOpen {
                    debugPrint("Error opening:\(settingUrl.absoluteString)")
                    // show error
                }
            }
      }else{ 
         if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
            print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true

           })
         }
      }
```

Enjoy :)..this worked for me.

Comment: anyone test this on iOS 11? Not working for me on iOS 11

Comment: Please do not use this. My app just got rejected because using ```Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION``` is not allowed

Comment: Thanks for informing but i have not faced the same what you are facing so i can check and update if i will get solution for it.

Comment: @LucasFarah how to do this then?

Comment: i have faced the app rejection for the same. Instead of opening the locations now we are just opening the settings screen. Let me know if some one finds any better solution for this.

Comment: yup, apps are getting rejected for using this. Got mine rejected today.

Comment: I had been rejected because of `Prefs:root=Privacy` today.

Comment: hi all Apple change in there policy . so app is getting rejected I am trying to explore for alternate but I have not found so far . :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [guy](https://github.com/cyanzhong). I figure out this URL Scheme `Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION` is only available in Today Widget, but no use in containing app.

In Today Widget, you can try this:

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"] completionHandler:nil];
```

More about system URL Schemes, you can see [here](https://github.com/cyanzhong/app-tutorials/blob/master/prefs.md).

This all I got. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open your app's setting center by opening`"App-Prefs:root=your app bundle id"`. This will be easy for user to change setting for your app.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. iOS7 ~ iOS11

But if you are uing the iOS11, you can only jump to the app's setting page

```
        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"];
        NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url2]){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url2 options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
            }
        } else {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url1]){
                if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url1 options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
                } else {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url1];
                }
            }
        }
```