# The way to jump to system setting's location service

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had do a test first,then post my answer:

The document said:`openURL:` is deprecated in iOS10.Use `openURL:options:completionHandler:` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to jump to system setting's location service on iOS10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940219/how-to-jump-to-system-settings-location-service-on-ios10)

Comment: @chedabob But no right answer for Objective-c there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before iOS 10,you can use:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"]];
```

After iOS 10,you'd better use:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"] 
options:[NSDictionary dictionary] 
completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Location Service Setting in Swift 3:

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION") {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3.0

```
let url = URL(string: "http://google.com")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else{
            NSLog("Cant open url")
        }
```