# App Tracking Transparency reset after user choice

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, idfa

I've just implemented the ATT request in my applications. It appears at the app first opening but I would like to show it again if the user wants to change his preferences from the app settings (internal).

I tried to call the requestTrackingAuthorization method again but it enters immediately to the completion handler. Is there a way to reset the status?

Comment: Not sure if it’s still possible but you can send them the app settings panel where there’s a tracking switch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940219/how-to-jump-to-system-settings-location-service-on-ios10

Comment: Useful workaround but it's a pity because that setting should be modifiable at any time without sending the user out of app

Comment: It is one-time only per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/3547037-requesttrackingauthorization)